# Why do we see large swings in Stored Procedure Performance

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a Stored Procedure where we're seeing high variance in performance. All the procedure does is read from a set of tables.

The issue is that it often starts off with <1s performance. Then, later in the week, the same queries run in >7s. We'd like to keep this <1s. The issue may be related to Parameter Sniffing but recompile statements do not positively OR negatively influence performance in this case. We've also reproduced this behavior on 2 independent systems of identical hardware.

Here's what we know:

- 3 of the 8 tables used have a high update/insert rate but with small amounts of data. Covering indexes are in place in every place where a table is touched. Most tables are very small and fast-access.
- Queries have require similar plan behavior: Look up 1 project and read it's 12-month summary at 1 row/month. Then pivot all 12 months of cost, rev, and budgets. (Each measure gets 12 columns so 36 columns outputed)

Here's what we've tried to no avail:

- Query hints

  > (ForceSeek)
- Run queries (with recompile) or forced all queries against the Stored Procedure with recompile

  > CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ProjectSummary @ProjectID INT
  >
  > WITH RECOMPILE
- Specified unknown variables using hints

Here's what's helped and where we have landed so far:

- Temp tables
- Force Fixed Plan with

  > OPTION (KEEPFIXED PLAN)
- Routinely run the following 2 statements to force a good query plan:

  > EXEC sp_recompile usp_ProjectSummary
  >
  > EXEC usp_ProjectSummary @ProjectID

Comment: Without seeing the query it's very difficult to guess why. You may try updating statistics on the tables involved. If you go that route don't update all the satisfies on all the tables - it may slow things down for everyone for a while.

Comment: Gosh it could be so many things. Parameter sniffing, stale statistics, poorly written query, no covering index, possibly indexing that makes it worse. With the table definitions, approximate row counts, index definitions and the actual query the best we can do is guess blindly.